# Windows Phone 7: Establishing which page is being activated during the Application_Activated event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, application-lifecycle, tombstoning

I am following the general best practice principles of restoring my persistent and none persistent state and objects when a tombstoned app is re-activated. Which can be found in this very good Microsoft article

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wp7trainingcourse_applicationlifetimewp7lab_topic2.aspx)

The samples only show a simple re-activation of the main page of an app. However as my application has multiple pages (any of which could be tombstoned and therfore re-activated) and each one is binding to a different ViewModel object. I would like to know how to ascertain which page is ultimately going to be activated so that I can selectivly deserialize and recover the correct ViewModel object for that page.

Or is the best practice to restore all ViewModels or is there another design pattern for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a simple pattern that is best described as -

1. In the application's Activated and Deactivated event, I send a message to subscribing pages.
2. The pages that subscribe to the message do the serialization/deserialization of data.

I am using [Laurent Bugnion's excellent MVVMLight library for Windows Phone 7](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/). Here is some sample code illustrating the message broadcast -

```
// Ensure that application state is restored appropriately
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
   Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage<AppEvent>(AppEvent.Activated, string.Empty));
}

// Ensure that required application state is persisted here.
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
   Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage<AppEvent>(AppEvent.Deactivated, string.Empty));
}
```

Within the constructor of a ViewModel class, I setup the subscription to the notification messages -

```
// Register for application event notifications
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<AppEvent>>(this, n =>
{
   switch (n.Content)
   {
      case AppEvent.Deactivated:
         // Save state here
         break;

      case AppEvent.Activate:
         // Restore state here
         break;
   }
}
```

I found that with this strategy, all the data relevant to the page that is bound to a ViewModel is saved and restored properly.

HTH, indyfromoz

Comment: Thanks for that. That looks great. I am also using MVVM Light. I will give this pattern a go this morning and let you know. I am fairly new to MVVM and I have not been using the messaging framework yet!